# Fixing invoice numbers in a CSV C++

Tags: c++

I have a customer who gets a csv of invoices from a supplier, most of this CSV is wrong, so i've made a small program which will fix it. This all works great except one part, the invoice numbers, this is most definitely a logic issue, and i am struggling to think of a way to do it.

I have pushed each column in the csv to a vector< string > for easy management like this:

```
    ifstream input(path);
if (input.is_open()) {
    for (string line; getline(input, line); )
    {
        auto arr = explode(line, ',');
        // Now create seperate arrays for each field. Field won't change as CSV is by number of commas.
        contact.push_back(arr[0]);
        InvoiceNumber.push_back(arr[10]);
        InvoiceDate.push_back(arr[12]);
        DueDate.push_back(arr[13]);
        Description.push_back(arr[15]);
        Quantity.push_back(arr[16]);
        UnitAmount.push_back(arr[17]);
        AccountCode.push_back(arr[19]);
        TaxType.push_back(arr[20]);

    }
}
```

The explode function is named that just because i use php a lot and it feels more intuitive to me. It's code is as follows:

```
vector<string> explode(string const & s, char delim){
vector<string> result;
istringstream iss(s);
for (string token; getline(iss, token, delim); ){
    result.push_back(move(token));
}
return result;
```

}

I then take this and loop it by Contact, just because they should all contain the same number of elements(and they seem to in practice). Sometimes the same customer will have 2 lines which have the same invoice number, by keeping them the same it will just add a new line to thier invoice. I need to add INV- prefix to them, and change the number to follow on from what the user inputs which is held by NumStart. I have tried to do this as follows:

```
for (int i = 1; i < contact.size(); i++) {
    if (InvoiceNumber[i] == splotch) { InvoiceNumber[i] = InvoiceNumber[i - 1]; }
    else {
        char temp[10];
        splotch = InvoiceNumber[i];
        InvoiceNumber[i] = itoa(NumStart + i, temp, 10);
        InvoiceNumber[i] = "INV-" + InvoiceNumber[i];       
    }
```

I created splotch which holds the last invoice number so that i can compare the current number to the previous invoice number WITHOUT the inv prefix(as the unmodified ones do not have this prefix).

However due to my doing this, the array is only setting a new number half the time, and so the invoice numbers skip like this:

https://gyazo.com/89007923ffad5df4c8bd7ce8b5a205e3

Converting between the vector string and int to try and make a 1 time store seems to write corrupt data somehow.

How can i make this increment correctly like 1001, 1002, 1003 and 1004 as opposed to the 1 3 5 9 nonsense i have going on?

Comment: Your `for` loop iterates over `contact.size()`, but you don't use `contact` anywhere in the loop (instead you index into `InvoiceNumber`). This seems like a problem (the "source" for `i`'s limits don't seem related to where you *use* `i`).

Comment: Sorry, i have clearly worded this very poorly. I apologize to everyone for the confusion i have caused. Actually since it's a Csv i decided the number of entries in contacts, and every other field would be the same, so just used it as it was the shortest name so least typing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You really just need to replace vecInput with your vector of invoices. This is also capable of printing it right when a duplicate invoice does not come directly after the first one. I don't know if this is desired or even a problem.

```
// heidi.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_map>


int main()
{
    const std::string sPrepend = "INV-";

    std::unordered_map<std::string, uint_fast32_t> mapRelations;

    std::vector<std::string> vecInput = {
        "330052", "330052", "330053", "330053", "330054", "330054"
    };

    std::string sStart;
    std::cout << "Please enter the start invoice: ";
    std::cin >> sStart;

    auto nStart = std::stoi(sStart);
    uint_fast32_t nCounter = 0;

    for (auto& invoice : vecInput)
    {
        if (mapRelations.find(invoice) == mapRelations.end())
        {
            mapRelations[invoice] = nCounter;
            std::cout << sPrepend + std::to_string(nStart + nCounter) << std::endl;
            nCounter++;
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << sPrepend + std::to_string(nStart + mapRelations[invoice]) << std::endl;
        }
    }

    std::cin.get();

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

[image: output]

Comment: Hm, yeah i think i did explain badly. This is the input https://gyazo.com/d89fbfe1e6d9a848c4bffbb92c07a5c1 and where there are 2 numbers the same i wish to keep that trend, hence the i-1 i had going on. Splotch is just a variable i thought up to hold the previous invoice number. So i am trying to make it go 1001 1001, 1002 1002 etc as per the example screenshot.(but i cannot always guarantee it will be in pairs

Comment: In that case can you not just literally loop through all of them and prepend "INV-"? Sounds like you don't need any conditions if you just want to keep the invoice number as is and want to preserve the fact that they can occur multiple times in a row

Comment: I don't wish to preserve the invoice numbers as they are, only the fact some are duplicated. I wish to change all the numbers to increment +1 for each unique number starting at NumStart which is what the user enters.

Comment: I have edited my post with code that works :) Its certainly not the most performant way to do it but its easy to read.

Answer (score 0):

As, far as I understand I have programmed this, The code is well commented so that you can understand. But I dont get what you need since your explanation is bad. I have less reputation to ask as a comment!

```
class Adder
{
private:
    // I think this is your vector we will be adding up all our invoice numbers
    std::vector<std::string> invoice_number;
    // This holds the current invoice no
    int currentInvoiceNumber;
public:
    Adder() { currentInvoiceNumber = 0; } // Initialize with a constructor IDK what is splotch
    void add_number(int no)
    {
        if (no == currentInvoiceNumber) invoice_number.push_back("INV-" + std::to_string(no += 1)); 
        else
        {
            currentInvoiceNumber = no;
            add_number(currentInvoiceNumber); // recursion could reduce some code
        }
    }
    // let us see what we got
    void show_output()
    {
        // we could use iterators to access those contents
        typedef std::vector<std::string>::iterator iterator;
        iterator itr1 = invoice_number.begin();
        iterator itr2 = invoice_number.end();
        for (iterator itr = itr1; itr!=itr2; ++itr)
        {
            std::cout << *itr<<"\n";
        }
    }
};
```

**we will see our sample input**

```
int main()
{
    Adder add;
    // for simplicity I used your input as arrays
    int arr[6] = { 1000,1000,1001,1001,1002,1002 };
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)add.add_number(arr[i]);
    add.show_output();
}
```

and the result is something like this which you want!

[image]

**Note**
1. I didn't understand your question fully, As far as I understand I have implemented. Please explain me briefly if you have any problem.
2. Sorry for the wrong camel casing like_this, Personally it is easier for my eyes!

**Latest edit**
If you need to pass the invoice no as a std::string , yet invoice no is a integer then you could do some little typecasting like this

```
// Un-tested code without any exception handling
    void add_number(std::string number)
    {
        int no = std::stoi(number);
        if (no == currentInvoiceNumber) invoice_number.push_back("INV-" + std::to_string(no += 1)); 
        else
        {
            currentInvoiceNumber = no;
            add_number(std::to_string(currentInvoiceNumber)); // recursion could reduce some code
        }
    }
```

to the method which adds the invoice no. Please make sure this method is not properly handled with try and catch. yet, your invoice no is like 1000,1001,1002.. n which seems to be an integer, I guess you may not face problems.

You can now modify the main method to pass string as the input

```
Adder add;
    // for simplicity I used your input as arrays
    std::string arr[6] = { "1000","1000","1001","1001","1002","1002" };
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)add.add_number(arr[i]);
    add.show_output();
```

Comment: I have re-worded my question does that make it clearer? Sorry for causing confusion. And would that function be able to accept a string vector as well as the int array you passed to it? Or do i want to be converting to int in my loop?

Comment: @heidisievert The method is capable of accepting <int> which I have seen in your screenshot the invoice no's are all integers and it gets converted to string with a little processing (increments and recursion) and every processed strings are pushed back to the vector of strings which is the final answer I guess.

Comment: @heidisievert you could also use the latest edit to make the method capable of accepting formal parameter as std::string.